# PHP printing to browser instead of CSV file

Tags: php, export-to-csv, fputcsv

Trying to create a csv file with an export from our database. This is the code im using:

```
if(isset($_POST["Export"])){

  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
  $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
  fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone'));  
  $query = "SELECT userID, name, email, phone from user ORDER BY userID DESC";  
  $result = mysql_query($query);  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
  {  
       fputcsv($output, $row);  
  }  
  fclose($output);
```

When I click the export button, it loads this PHP page with the correct results in the browser. However I can't get the results to store in a file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those headers are exacly how I'm creating CSV-downloads (without the utf-8 though, but that shouldn't be a problem). Possible issues: 1st verify the headers are sent to the browser (F12 then Network-tab), possible (unwanted) output before you set the headers will break them (also raises a warning in your error_log). 2nd: try quoting the filename `filename="data.csv"`, just to be sure, 3rd: try anonther browser to verify this isn't a browser bug (yours wouldn't be the first)

Comment: Hey @PetervanderWal, Thanks for the response.
1. Im seeing the correct header with all the database data in the preview.
2. Tried quoting the filename, and nothing, unfortunately.
3. Tried in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of these content types:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: Now its just opening to a blank PHP page (where there was the correct output before). Could this be a permissions issue?

Comment: This will store the file server-side. As I read the question correctly, Matture is trying to create a 'Download CSV'-link.

Comment: That's correct @PetervanderWal. I would like to download the file client side.

Comment: @matture I misunderstood your question. You want to trigger a file download of your output rather than just output to the browser the raw text. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`just before your file output.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove the Content-Disposition header and set the Content-Type header to plain text:

`header('Content-Type: text; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any other `print` or `echo` commands in your script.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `fclose($output);` line.